# How to ignore white space and marks when encrypting a string variable in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to encrypt a string with white space and a question mark on it, for example, I am going to encrypt all the alphabet into numbers based on the order of the alphabet, but when I turn the string into numbers white space and question mark also gets enumerated how do I ignore that?
example)

```
int main() {
  string alphabet;
  int encrypted_code;
  int first_int = 1, second_int = 2, third_int = 3;
  string text = "hey what is your name?";
  for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    alphabet += ch;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    encrypted_code = alphabet.find(text[i]);
    if (i == 0 || i % 3 == 0) {
      encrypted_code = encrypted_code + first_int;
    }
    cout << encrypted_code << " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: `string alphabet(“abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz”);` is faster and portable (the codes for letters are not required to be adjacent).

Answer (score 2):

Use an if statement to only work on letters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
  if ('a' <= text[i] && text[i] <= 'z') {
    // rest of your code goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `isalpha(text[i])`. It’s doesn’t build in assumptions about the character encoding and it’s probably faster.

Comment: @PeteBecker the original code uses only lowercase a-z, so the answer should be fine. As to being faster, I'm doubtful, since isalpha needs to check more things than is the character between two values, and modern compilers have a very easy time optimizing this kind of pattern

Comment: @EyalK. — `isalpha` is typically just a table lookup and a mask. So, on modern hardware, two CPU instructions and no branches. And it handles non-contiguous encodings, which both the original code and the code in this answer will get wrong. Granted, that’s uncommon, but such encodings do exist.

Comment: @PeteBecker Interesting. I was sure it was doing some locale shenanigans like most of the common functions that deal with characters

Comment: @EyalK. — the locale is managed by selecting the table. One table for all the `isxxx` functions.

Comment: @EyalK. — but there are no locale adjustments here; `a` etc. are in the source encoding, which is determined by the compiler at compile time and can’t be changed by the program.